# Sending a random number into a tag that refreshes itself

Tags: javascript, random

I try to send a random number into a tag in my script to test how my page will react.

So here's what i've got.

```
<script>
    display_number = 1.5684651 ;
    display = display_number;
    function DIS_EN() {
        var num = display;
        var n = num.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("display_value").innerHTML = n;
    }
</script>
```

Rignt now the `display_number` is fixed to `1.5684651`, what I want is to get a random number in the `display_number` tag. This information will come from an external page and it will vary so that's why I want a random number.

How can I do that? I know I can use a `Math.random` to generate a random number but I don't know how to show it in my `display_number` tag...

**EDIT:**

One more thing: I want it to change by itself... I tried `setInterval(function(){Math.random},2000)`, but it doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's my latest code, with the `setInterval` in it

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){display_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1.0E+10) + 1);}, 2000);
    display = display_number;
    function DIS_EN() {
        var num = display;
        var n = num.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("display_value").innerHTML = n;
    }
</script>
```

I get a new value everytime I refresh the page only when I add the `setInterval` I get a blank page...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) from the w3schools:

```
// Returns a number from 0 to 1
display_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // Returns 1 - 10
```

To make this go by itself, just wrap the whole line inside of your setInterval code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    display_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // Returns 1 - 10
    // Update your UI here...
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Please find a more reliable source. Possible https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random?

Comment: it's almost it, I just need it to change by itself without refreshing the page... Any idea?

Comment: I tried to do as you said with the `setInterval`, but now I only have a blank page. Is there another way?

Comment: What's your updated code?  It's hard to say why your page would be blank after what I gave you.  I'm assuming however you "Updated your UI" would be causing the issue

Comment: This code is generating an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: display is not defined (anonymous function)

Comment: Any luck with this yet?  Do you declare your `display` and `display_number` outside the scope of the function?  I know global variables are bad, but before setInterval in your code, you could try to declare `var display, dislpay_number;`  Inside your `setInterval`, that `display_number` may be out of scope once you assign `display = display_number;`.

Comment: It worked! I just had to put every variable into the function `DIS_EN()` and add `setInterval(function(){DIS_EN()},2000;` in my script, instead of leaving `display` and `display_number` above the function, like this: 
`function DIS_EN(){
var display_number = Math.random;
var display = display_number;
[...]`
Although thanks for the advice